# jquery GET adds current url to my url parameter

Tags: jquery

I have a GET request in a document. The current page I am on includes that document and then the document is executed. The issue is the document is found when included but the GET request is not because the request that is being sent by GET (according to firebug) is `http://www.site.com/watch/http//www.site.com/file/doc.php` when the request should just be requested by GET to `http//www.site.com/file/doc.php`. The current page I am on is `http://www.site.com/watch/123456` where **watch** is an alias for `video.php?vid_id=`. Anyone have any ideas as to why this is happening?

```
         $.getJSON("http//www.site.com/file/doc.php?action=view&load=initial&page="+page+"&vid_id="+vid_id+"&username="+username+"&t=" + (new Date()), function(json) {  
  var html = '';
  for(i=0; i < json.length; i++) {
    html += prepare(json[i]);
  }
  $('#shoutbox-list').append(html).find('li').fadeIn(1500);
   $('div[id="chunk"]').fadeIn(1500);
});
```

Comment: Instead of `$('div[id="chunk"]')`, use `$('#chunk')`, it's much faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to insert a colon into your URL so that it's a valid resource identifier:

e.g. change:

```
$.getJSON("http//www.site.com/....
```

to

```
$.getJSON("http://www.site.com/....
               ^
```

Comment: aww man I can't believe I forgot that. Thanks so much Dexter!